# Dell Inspiron 1545 volume keys

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, dell-inspiron

Are the volume keys on a Dell Inspiron 1545 supposed to be arched / raised ?

Is it a touchy-feely thing, like finding the F and J keys ?

Answer (score 0):

from looking at photos online, it does not seem so, there seems to be a consistent level to the keys. But I have also noticed this keyboard is available for pretty cheap if you felt the need to replace it :D